# Update mysql table to swap the entire rows

Tags: mysql

i have to swap data in row for the entire table. I've searched for the solutions but it is only for two rows. That is not what i'm searching for. I've to swap the entire table's row. The row would only contain two type of data. Like 0 or 1.

My mysql table looks like this.

```
*CustomerId             Band         Gender*
Kurt Cobain            Nirvana      Male
John Mayer             JohnMayer    Male
Katy Perry             Katy Perry   Female
Lana Del Rey           Lana Del     Female
Axl Rose               GNR          Male
```

After the swap i want my table to look like this.

```
*CustomerId            Band         Gender*
Kurt Cobain            Nirvana      Female
John Mayer             JohnMayer    Female
Katy Perry             Katy Perry   Male
Lana Del Rey           Lana Del     Male
Axl Rose               GNR          Female
```

I want my ID to be same as it is. 
Thank you !!!!!

Comment: You need to swap female to male and vice versa?

Comment: Yes !!! I've just given a example. Don't take it literally. My need for the table represents this.

Comment: `UPDATE TABLE weird_gender_bands SET Gender = IF(Gender='Female', 'Male', 'Female');`

Answer (score 0):

If the values you want to swap are 0 and 1, you can do something like:

```
UPDATE table_name SET Gender = 1 - Gender;
```

if your current values is 1, it will do this (1-1 =0), else if your value is 0, it will do this(1-0 = 1)

**OR**

If you are working with strings, you can simply do something like:

```
UPDATE table_name SET Gender = IF(Gender="Male", "Female", "Male");
```

This query does a basic if statement, if the gender field is `Male`, it will set it to `Female`, else, it will set it to `Male`

**Here is a working [DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c1722/1/0)**

Comment: @AnkitShrestha i have updated my answer for 2nd query's description, It works, what error are you getting?

Comment: BUT CAN YOU EXPLAIN WHY MYSQL WORKBENCH DIDN"T EXECUTE THIS QUERY BUT COMMAND LINE DID ???

Comment: @AnkitShrestha I think you should open a new question for that

Comment: @AnkitShrestha i updated my answer to include a demo for your question

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table SET gender=CASE WHEN gender='female' THEN 'male' WHEN gender='male' THEN 'female' ELSE NULL END
```

Comment: not working... are you sure.???? also can you provide links for these type of query !!! Thank you

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH !!! IT WORKED !!!! 
 
BUT CAN YOU EXPLAIN WHY MYSQL WORKBENCH DIDN"T EXECUTE THIS QUERY BUT COMMAND LINE DID ???

Comment: Sorry but I'm not familiar with MySql workbench, I use the command line.
Glad to help anyway